# How do I restore Ethernet after upgrating to Windows 8.1?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1

My LAN stopped working after upgrading to Windows 8.1.

Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller

Network adapters message:

> "Your computer's system firmware does not include enough information
>   to properly configure and use this device.  To use this device,
>   contact your computer manufacturer to obtain a firmware or BIOS
>   update. (Code 35)"

How can I restore my Ethernet?

Comment: What happened after you updated the bios / drivers?

Comment: provide some details about your hardware and try the latest driver from Realtek: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false